# Filebrowser that allows to see the most recently created file immediately

Tags: windows, file-management

The goal: I just want to see an icon of a file immediately after its creation (in a specified directory). The file will be created by a different program, I'm just waiting for it to appear.

I tried many file managers, but got no results. They all (incl. Windows Explorer itself) have the same problem: if I keep the folder opened, the new file becomes appended somewhere at the bottom, but since there is no automatic scrolling to the very bottom, that file is hidden!

**Note:** Neither F5 (refresh) nor reordering (by creation time) are not an option - this will take too much of my time. I need to **focus** the new file **automatically after creation,** so it becomes visible immediately, without any additional steps. All I want is to not waste my time focusing the new file!

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: Of course, the files will be created by another program, not Explorer itself. If I create a file using Explorer, the problem does not exist because that file is focused and visible immediately after creation...

Comment: @lyricallywicked valid points. I've integrated that directly with your question to make it obvious to "new readers". Let's remove the corresponding comments now to keep the page clean (makes it easier to "focus" :D)

Comment: Is your goal to open the file (so would a program that automatically opens any new file in a directory solve your problem) or do you want to be aware of that file (so would a program that automatically informs you of a new file be okay?) or what do you want to do with the file? Something new every time or always the same thing?

Comment: They all (incl. Windows Explorer itself) have the same problem -> which ones did you try?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I tried portable versions of CubicExplorer, Explorer++, FreeCommander, Q-Dir, Xenon File Manager - found in [portableapps.com/apps/utilities](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities).

Comment: @AngeloFuchs: I want to keep the folder opened (in some file browser/manager), and when a new file arrives to that folder, its icon must be visible immediately without, say, manual scrolling. It doesn't matter what I want to do with the file, all I want is to **see** it immediately after creation. Maybe double-click it, maybe right-click it to show the context menu...

Comment: @lyricallywicked I understood that much; To explain my questions a bit more: I have the impression that you have a stopper in your workflow and you have thought about a possible solution that would help you (which is this question). But maybe there is a better solution to your original problem. So, I'm asking you to describe your workflow a bit more detailed. Where does the file come from, where should it go? What should happen on it. If there are multiple answers to that, could you give two examples?

Comment: Have a look at http://leelusoft.blogspot.de/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) (and numerous others), which lets you sort a directory by date.

[image]   (unfortunately, this shows sort by name - but I often sort by date (and you can infer it from [this part of the FAQ](http://www.ghisler.com/efaquser.htm#dirsort))).

Btw, Total Commander will auto-refresh the directory when the new file appears).

[Update] it seems that you would be limited to having TC open and scrolled to the top, sorted by date. If you leave TC open only for that porpoise then you can do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find any "official" portable version of Total Commander, and I'm not going to follow instructions of [www.ghisler.com/usbinst.htm](http://www.ghisler.com/usbinst.htm). Is there any alternative that has a portable version?

Comment: Sure, no problem. When installing, you are given an option as to where to store the program data - just chose "program directory" and that's a portable install. I have done so, and it worked. I have also done a full install, then copied to USB stick and it worked,; however, it (obviously) didn't copy my configuration. So, just choose  "program directory" to store data when installing & you will have what you want.

Comment: I downloaded Total Commander Installer [Ghisler Software GmbH]. Double-clicked, and... what??? It asks for admin rights **before the installation**! No. This is not a portable app.

Comment: Does it? I don't remember that? But,t hen I bought & registered my copy back with Windows 95 (IIRC) and since then I have just copied the directory from PC to PC ever since. Ok, are you willing to instill **once** as admin, and say that data should be in the program directory? After that, you can copy it from machine to machine. If not,t hen use http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/freecommander_portable but I can assure you that it is not as full featured as TC. I twill, however, do what you want (as will most (all?) two pane Norton Commander clones)

Comment: I tried FreeCommander already. No, it does not focus (scroll to) the most recently created file automatically. Actually, I even doubt if TotalCommander will do this.

Comment: Here are steps to experiment. 1. Create a directory with, say, 50-100 text files (so that the scrollbar is visible), make sure the files are ordered by creation date. 2. Open this directory with some file manager/browser, **and move this window somewhere near the side of the screen**. 3. Open Notepad.exe and resize its window, so that opened folder is visible. 4. Create a text file with Notepad and save it in that directory. 5. Check what's going on in the window near the screen side. Can you see the new file immediately?

Comment: TC does *not* need admin rights to install. I just tested it, behind a very nasty company firewall that won't let me install **anything** (only the IT dept can do that). I downloaded and ran the installer and chose to put data in the program, directory (I suspect that trying to write to the registry would require admin rights, but you do not need to do that).  I opened a directory with a few 100 files, sorted by date, and scrolled down, than created a new file in notepad. TC did not auto-scroll up Alas. However, when I was already scrolled to the top, the new file did appear there ...

Comment: So, it seems that you would be limited to having TC open **and** scrolled to the top, sorted by date. If you leave TC open only for that porpoise then you can do what you want. Beyond that, I am sorry, I can help no more. Good luck!

Comment: @Mawg could you edit the last to comments into the answer? That way its clear how it serves the purpose of the question.

Comment: Is TC under active development? I see the current version was released more than a year ago..

Comment: Well, he developed it actively for 15 years already. I can't think what more features could be added. There's simply no competition. If you want to know the status, email the author - he is very friendly (or ask on the forum). But, as long as it does what you want, do you care?